# How to Add an item to the start menu in Winsows CE 6.0?

Tags: windows-ce

I am building a WinCE6.0 image for VIA 8237S board. I want to include items like              (shutdown,logoff,Control Panel) to the WinCE start Menu.Please guide me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the strong feeling you didn't do much searching before asking here.  The number one search result for "Windows CE Start Menu" is [an MSDN article by Mike Hall explaining exactly what you're after](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehall/archive/2007/07/26/adding-applications-to-the-windows-ce-start-menu.aspx).